# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when trying to extend Class (using a YoutubeFragment in a android-library for Unity)

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, noclassdeffounderror, android-library

I'm trying to add a [YouTubePlayerFragment](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment) to a Unity Android Project. I've succeeded in adding normal Views showing buttons and text and whatnot, but I get halted when I try to extend the class I'm using to do this to a YoutubePlayerFragment. I keep getting a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

```
04-20 04:12:18.390    7404-7404/com.example.OSHook E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.OSHook, PID: 7404
        java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.OSHook.YoutubeController
        at com.example.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity.onCreate(UnityPlayerNativeActivity.java:66)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

On the line com.example.OSHook.YoutubeController fragment = new com.example.OSHook.YoutubeController( UnityPlayerNativeActivity.this, rootView);
in the following code:

```
package com.example.player;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.NativeActivity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.example.OSHook.YoutubeController;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;

public class UnityPlayerNativeActivity extends NativeActivity
{
    protected UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer;     // don't change the name of this variable; referenced from native code

    // UnityPlayer.init() should be called before attaching the view to a layout - it will load the native code.
    // UnityPlayer.quit() should be the last thing called - it will unload the native code.


    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().takeSurface(null);
        setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_565);

        mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
        if (mUnityPlayer.getSettings ().getBoolean ("hide_status_bar", true))
            getWindow ().setFlags (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        int glesMode = mUnityPlayer.getSettings().getInt("gles_mode", 1);
        boolean trueColor8888 = false;
        mUnityPlayer.init(glesMode, trueColor8888);

        View playerView = mUnityPlayer.getView();
        setContentView(playerView);
        playerView.requestFocus();

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup)UnityPlayerNativeActivity.this.findViewById(android.R.id.content);


        com.example.OSHook.YoutubeController fragment = new com.example.OSHook.YoutubeController(UnityPlayerNativeActivity.this, rootView);

        //FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        //FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        //fragmentTransaction.add(playerView.getId(), fragment);
        //fragmentTransaction.commit();



    }
```

UnityPlayerNativeActivity resides in the com.example.player package, YoutubeController.java and the YouTubePlayerAPI.jar in com.example.OSHook. I build this project to a library, and load the jar in Unity. The code works perfect when YoutubeController.java doesn't extend YouTubeFragment, it adds views over the Unity player's view.

I guess that the final Unity Android build can't find YoutubePlayer.jar, but I can't find anything to support nor fix it. Anybody any idea on what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Library in an Android library referenced by an Android Project throws NoClassDefFound](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308331/java-library-in-an-android-library-referenced-by-an-android-project-throws-nocla)

Comment: BTW: you should not use `com.example..` package name

Comment: Ow wow. Just import YoutubePlayerAPI.jar into Unity as well huh. So dumb of me :D. It's late. Thanks man!

Comment: donfuxx: I know, it's just a test name :)